# Getting duplicate data in ssis package

Tags: ssis, duplicates

I am creating a ssis package. Here is the scenario, I have got two servers Server A and Server B. I have created a package that transfers the data from one Server A to Server B. The Server A gets updated daily. I have also scheduled a job to run daily at 5am. When the job runs it appends the data from the Server A to Server B. Can somebody help me in solving this problem?

Comment: So you are inserting the same data more than once. If you have any unique key in your table, use expression to build a query to retrieve only new records. Store the expression in a variable and choose SQL Command from Variable in the OLEDB Source.

Answer (score 0):

I think you created the SSIS package which inserts the data from Server A to Server B. So my suggestion is to create `data flow` which Stages the Server 1 data into Server B. After that use the `SQL Execute Task` to run a batch update which updates the target table in Server B. So there will not be any append.

Hope this helps!